# Characteristic function of Dirichlet Process

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Suppose $P \sim \text{DP}(\alpha,G) $ where $G \sim N(0,1)$ is the base measure and $\alpha > 0$ is the concentration parameter. The stick breaking representation says that $P$ can be expressed as \begin{align*} P = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} W_j \delta_{\theta_j} \; \; \; \; \; \; \; , \; \; \; \; W_j = V_j \prod_{l=1}^{j-1} (1-V_l)    \end{align*}
where $\theta_j \stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(0,1) $ and $ V_l \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \text{Beta}(1,\alpha) $.

It follows that the characteristic function of $P$ is given by $$ \varphi_{P}(t) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} W_j e^{\mathbf{i}  t \delta_j  } $$
It seems intuitively clear to me that $\left| \varphi_P(t) \right|$ is bounded away from zero (even at large $t$) with high probability but I don't know how to make this rigorous. Specifically, how does $$ \mathbb{P}( \left| \varphi_P(t)   \right| \leq \epsilon ) $$
behave as $ |t| \rightarrow \infty $ and $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.